# Getting the wrong number of days from JS Date object

Tags: javascript

This is probably something really simple and I missed something somewhere but I need to find how many days in a month and one issue I am running into is when I run the following code I don't get the right number of days

Septemper ( should be 30 but get 31 ):

```js
const date = new Date("2021/9/11");
const daysInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
console.log(date)
console.log(daysInMonth)
```

August ( should be 31 and do indeed get 31 )

```js
const date = new Date("2021/8/11");
const daysInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
console.log(date)
console.log(daysInMonth)
```

October ( should be 31 but get 30 )

```js
const date = new Date("2021/10/11");
const daysInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
console.log(date)
console.log(daysInMonth)
```

As you can see I am not getting the expected answer out of them and so I thought the months start counting from 0 but since I am supplying a string that shouldn't matter. I am hoping you can help me figure this out!

Comment: "The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) return zero-based month number, where January is 0 and December is 11

So you need use `date.getMonth() + 1`

Answer (score 1):

as a date.getMonth() returns 9 which is October cause index start form 0, but while passing the parameter we need to pass the general index number of the month for that you have to do +1

```js
const date = new Date("2021/10/11");
const daysInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
console.log(date)
console.log(daysInMonth)
```

Comment: FYI 9 is not September but October ;)